# POST http://localhost:8000/api/projects/ 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, angular, laravel, typescript, jwt

I'm working on a rest api project, I'm using Laravel and Angular. To resume, my project is like a project manager. I've got 4 tables: user, project, project_user and status. [image] So when a user create a project, he writes just the name and the project is created. The creator_id is the current user id. For the backend, I'm using Laravel JWT for the auth. And this is the code of the controller to create a project: [image]

Project model:

```
class Project extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',  'creator_id', 'status_id'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'created_at', 'updated_at'
    ];

    protected $table = 'projects';

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->select( 'email', 'date_of_birth', 'firstname', 'lastname');
    }

    public function status()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Status::class);
    }
}
```

So the route in backend works, I tried with Postman and all is good. But I've got a problem with this route to create a project in frontend. It doesn't work and I've got the error 500 (Internal Server Error). When I inspect the web page, in security, I've got this message:
[image]

This is my angular code:

```
export class AddProjectComponent implements OnInit {

  project = {
    name: '',
  };

  submitted = false;
  constructor(private projectService: ProjectService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  createProject(): void {
    const data = {
      name: this.project.name,
    };
    this.projectService.create(data)
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          console.log(response);
          this.submitted = true;
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  }

  newProject(): void {
    this.submitted = false;
    this.project = {
      name: ''
    };
  }
}
```

project.service.ts

```
  create(data): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.post(`http://localhost:8000/api/projects/`, data);
  }
```

I don't know why it doesn't work because my user is well connected, i've got his auth_token in the local storage.

Someone can help me pls ? ^^

I think I have put the most useful files but if they are missing I can add them to you.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you set timestamp false in model ?

Comment: @JohnLobo No, i don't

Comment: add model code in question

Comment: sorry my mistake i thought its created_at but its creator_id .you are not passing creator_id .so check dd($request->all()) has creator_id.look like its empty or request doesnt have creator_id

Comment: always enable debug true for testing in development

Comment: @JohnLobo dd($request->all()) has creator_id

Comment: does it has value  ?

Comment: @JohnLobo yes it has value (and the good value)

Comment: try once this $request->merge(['creator_id'=>Auth::id()]) instead of add

Comment: Please share more details. When an error 500 occurs, there is usually something written to your server's error log

Comment: @JohnLobo It works with merge ! Thank you so much ! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is with  `$request-request->add(['creator_id'=>Auth::id()])`

instead of that use `request merge`.

```
$request->merge(['creator_id'=>Auth::id()])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is right there in the error message. creator_id does not have a default value which means you HAVE to pass a value to it for it to create the row in the DB